# Meteor - How does Telescope load more posts without re-rendering?

Tags: javascript, meteor, telescope

I'm trying to figure out how to implement the `load more` functionality like [Telescope](https://github.com/TelescopeJS/Telescope). This is what I have originally:

```
// Iron Router
Router.route('/posts', {
  name: 'posts.index',

  waitOn: function () {
    return Meteor.subscribe('posts', Session.get('postsLimit');
  },

  data: function () {
    return { posts: Posts.find({}, { sort: { createdAt: -1 } }) };
  },

  action: function () {
    this.render();
  }

});


// client/views/posts_list.html
<ul>
  {{#each posts}}
    <li>{{ title }}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
<a href"#" class="load-more">Load more</a>


// client/views/posts_list.js
var POSTS_INCREMENT = 3;
Session.setDefault('postsLimit', POSTS_INCREMENT);

Template.PostsIndex.events({
   'click .load-more': function (e, tmpl) {
       Session.set('postsLimit', Session.get('postsLimit') + POSTS_INCREMENT);
       return false;
   }
 }
});
```

It makes sense that Meteor will rerender the list when the `postsLimit` changes. I'm just curious how Telescope did it **without re-rendering** the list and only render the new posts. From what I see from the [code](https://github.com/TelescopeJS/Telescope), instead of storing the limit in the `Session`, the author uses the route `top/:limit?` and instead of using `waitOn`, they use `onBeforeAction`. It's hard to pinpoint which part of the code helps prevent re-rendering the list. Could someone please help explain in detail how they did it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The part that triggers the re-rendering is actually `waitOn`. By using `waitOn`, you're telling Iron Router to redirect you to the `loading` template while you wait, which is what triggers the re-rendering and sticks you back up at the top of the page.

This is `waitOn`'s job, and it works great when going from page to page, but is obviously not ideal when re-rendering the same page.

By the way, note that the new `subscriptions` option can *also* trigger the same behavior (if you've set a global `loading` template).

So this is why we're using `onBeforeAction` in this specific case. This pattern is explained in more details in [Discover Meteor](http://discovermeteor.com), by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is helpful but to load more posts all you have to do is add `{{> UI.dynamic template=postsLoadMore}}` in the postList template.

```
<template name="posts_list">
  {{> UI.dynamic template=postsListIncoming data=incoming}}
  <div class="posts-wrapper grid grid-module">
    <div class="posts list">
      {{#each posts}}
        {{> UI.dynamic template=post_item}}
      {{/each}}
    </div>
  </div>
  {{> UI.dynamic template=postsLoadMore}}
</template>
```

Comment: Don't think it will help. Because `postsLoadMore` template is just a link `top/xx` and a loading spinner. Clicking on the link will take you to a new route with `xx` posts, how does it help not re-rendering the list again?